# Add prefix and reset index in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Here's what I usually do in pandas

```
cdr = datamonthly.pivot(index="msisdn", columns="last_x_month", values="arpu_sum").add_prefix('arpu_sum_l').reset_index()
```

But what I did in Pyspark

```
cdr = datamonthly.groupBy("msisdn").pivot("last_x_month").sum("arpu_sum")
```

I cant find alternative for add_prefix('arpu_sum_l').reset_index()

Comment: Can you add sample input and desired output

Comment: Also there is no concept of `index` within a Spark DataFrame

Comment: How about prefix?

Comment: You can find lot more examples here https://github.com/Evergreenies/data_engineering_pyspark/blob/main/pyspark_scripts/india_covid_19_analysis.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing similar to pandas' `add_prefix` in spark when doing pivot. But, you can try a workaround like creating a column from concatenation of the custom prefix string and the value of the column to be pivoted.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cdr = datamonthly.withColumn("p", F.expr("concat('arpu_sum_l_', last_x_month)")).groupBy("msisdn").pivot("p").sum("arpu_sum")
```